# Python Multiprocessing Class Fails when Called from Local Package

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, package, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to write a package that contains a class which makes use of the multiprocessing package.  I will use a class that prints out "Hello, person", where person is an element in a array of strings, to illustrate the problem.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, people):
        self.people = people

    class _task(object):
        def __init__(self, person):
            self.person = person

        def __call__(self):
            self.greet(self.person)

        def greet(self, person):
            print('Hello, {}'.format(person))

    class _consumer(mp.Process):
        def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
            mp.Process.__init__(self)
            self.task_queue = task_queue
            self.result_queue = result_queue

        def run(self):
            while True:
                next_task = self.task_queue.get()
                if next_task is None:
                    # poison pill
                    self.task_queue.task_done()
                    break
                answer = next_task()
                self.task_queue.task_done()
                self.result_queue.put(answer)

    def greet(self):
        # establish communication queues
        tasks = mp.JoinableQueue()
        results = mp.Queue()

        # start consumers
        num_consumers = len(self.people)
        consumers = [self._consumer(tasks, results)
                     for ii in range(num_consumers)]
        for w in consumers:
            w.start()

        # enqueue jobs
        for person in self.people:
            tasks.put(self._task(person))

        # add a poison pill for each consumer
        for ii in range(num_consumers):
            tasks.put(None)

        # wait for tasks to finish
        tasks.join()
```

This main script is test.py:

```
import hello

if __name__ == '__main__':
    people = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Clarissa', 'David', 'Elizabeth', 'Frank',
              'Gertrude', 'Harry']
    hi = hello.Hello(people)
    hi.greet()
```

The package is currently part of one folder and is arranged over one layer.

```
hello/
    __init__  # from .hello_world import Hello
    hello_world.py  # contains class
test.py
```

If I run the script test.py from a python console I get the output I expect:

```
Hello, Alice
Hello, Bob
Hello, Clarissa
Hello, David
Hello, Elizabeth
Hello, Frank
Hello, Gertrude
Hello, Harry
```

If I try to run test.py from an ipython console it hangs and the kernel displays an error

```
ImportError: No module named 'hello'
```

If I copy the class into the top of test.py, import only multiprocessing and run from either a python console or ipython console, then I get the correct output.

I'm running 64-bit python 3 on windows 7.  You can find the package at [my github](https://github.com/Rhys314/test).

Why doesn't this work in an ipython console?

Comment: First thing to check is the differences in `sys.path` between the two ways you run the file, if they were the same I'd expect no difference but it's possible that iPython starts in a different working directory.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen When the script is executed os.getcwd() shows the same for both python and ipython consoles and the runfile command in the ipython console takes the correct cwd.  The paths are mostly the same too, the ipython console has an extra ~\settings\ipython entry but that shouldn't make the difference.